# Matplotlib Pandas barplot uppercase widtH bug?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

This appears to be a bug, though I cannot figure out why or where it is coming from, I have not been able to find an issue for this on github in part because it is case sensitive...

plotting a barplot in pandas with a width paramter:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [3, 2, 1]])
df.plot(kind='bar', width=1)
```

[image]

The same plot with a `widtH` parameter note the capital H:

```
df.plot(kind='bar', widtH=1)
```

[image]

```
print(pd.__version__)
print(mpl.__version__)

0.20.3
2.1.0
```

If this is a bug, can someone point me to the relevant issue? If it is not a bug what is the intended purpose of this?

Comment: should it be 'width' ?

Comment: @Wen Of course, but that is not my question

Comment: If this is not an appropriate question for SO please explain why. I am genuinely curious about the behavior of this code, which I do not understand at all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, `widtH` is not a documented argument to `plot`. Using a non-documented argument allows anything to happen; and hence I would not consider this to be a bug. Just as you would not consider it a bug that when calling `df.plot(kind='bar', i_am_so=True)` it raises an error.

From the pandas side, there is nothing strange here. Pandas `plot` function takes an argument `width` (case sensitive, lower case). If this is supplied its internal attribute `bar_width` is set to the given value, if not, a default of `0.5` is used [see [l.1167 of plotting/_core.py in current master](https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/blob/7627ccaf9442f4101afda69b6077e7f035e23543/pandas/plotting/_core.py#L1167)]

```
self.bar_width = kwargs.pop('width', 0.5)
```

Any other keyword arguments are passed on to the matplotlib bar function. Hence `matplotlib.axes._axes.bar` will be called with `widtH=1` as keyword argument, just like

```
pyplot.bar(... , width=0.5, widtH=1)
```

The unexpected result of this is that it indeed produces a plot with a bar of width 1.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.bar(1,2,width=0.5, widtH=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Note that the bar is ranging from x=0.75 to x=1.75. It is thus indeed 1 unit wide, as specified by `widtH`. Also note that without this argument we would see the bar centered at position x=1 as desired, ranging from x=0.75 to x=1.25, as `width=0.5` suggests. So the left corner of the bar is such as we would expect it.

What happens here is the following. A bar centered at position 1 is created with a width of 0.5. This bar is a `Rectangle` object. Now again all arguments which are unknown to the `bar` function are passed on to the underlying artist, which is a `Rectangle`. The rectangle will try to use these arguments to update its properties. This updating involves a cast to lower case, [line 888 of artist.py in the `Artist`'s `update` method](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/e36822f3956d2d60eb4fa6dad609488f9d1d7cae/lib/matplotlib/artist.py#L888) is

```
k = k.lower()
```

Since `"widtH".lower() == "width"`, the artist now updates its width to `1`. Its lower left corner stays the same, but instead of extending up to x=1.25, it will extend to 0.75 + 1 = 1.75.

Coming back to the pandas plot, this is exactly what we observe. The bars start at their desired position, but their width is extended to 1 unit.

I guess that's the whole story. Maybe as a take home message: Don't use undocumented arguments, or if you do, don't be surprised on what happens.

Comment: Thank you for such detailed answer, this is really helpful! Part of me would argue that using undocumented arguments should result in an error (for exactly the reason that prompted my question). Regardless this makes much more sense now

Comment: Ya well, this is an unlucky chain of events here. Pandas will not raise an error because it is not responsible for keyword arguments of matplotlib bar function. The bar function will not raise an error because it trusts Artist to raise the error if any invalid argument is given. Artist itself does not consider `wIdTh` to be invalid. So if anything one may argue that `Artist` should not take upper case arguments. On the other hand there may actually be a reason for it doing so.